# multiple matches REGEX

Tags: ios, regex, nsattributedstring

Hi i am using regex to match string inside brackets, and using that range to set attributes in attributedString.

the code right here only extracts one range, regex is working but i need to setup the second range assignment.

```
 NSString *mainString = @"Main Term  (Rounded) [Square] ~Italic~ (Rounded) [Square] ~Italic~";
    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:mainString];
NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *squareBracketsRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\[(.*?)\\]" options:0 error:&error];
    NSRange squareBracketsRange = [squareBracketsRegex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:mainString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, mainString.length)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:squareBracketsRange];
cell.textLabel.attributedText = string;
```

Comment: `-matchesInString:options:range:` or `enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:`. for further information: https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the rangeOfFirstMatchInString, so obviously you are only getting the first match of your regex.

You can use a code similar to the one in Apple NSRegularExpression documentation to loop through all the found matches of the regex.

```
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
     NSRange matchRange = [match range];
     NSRange firstHalfRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
     NSRange secondHalfRange = [match rangeAtIndex:2];
}
```